# Postgres sql to merge time that's 1 minute apart into the interval

Tags: postgresql

The requirement is to merge time that are less than or equal to 1 minutes apart into the same interval.

For example
input is a row of timestamps:
`"2023-08-10T18:30:30", "2023-08-10T18:31:00","2023-08-10T18:31:30","2023-08-10T18:35:00","2023-08-10T18:35:30",`

Expected output: `"18:30:30-18:31:30", "18:35:00-18:35:30"`

My idea was to use generate_series with the min and max of given time and then join with the original time. But not sure how to generate expected result

---

**sample data**

```
SELECT time FROM (values 
   ('2023-08-10T18:30:30')
  ,('2023-08-10T18:31:00')
  ,('2023-08-10T18:31:30')
  ,('2023-08-10T18:35:00')
  ,('2023-08-10T18:35:30')
  ,('2023-08-10T18:36:00')
  ,('2023-08-10T18:37:00')
  ,('2023-08-10T18:37:30')
  ) s(time)
```

**expected output**

- 2023-08-10T18:31:00 is in 1 minute interval bewtween 2023-08-10T18:30:30 and 2023-08-10T18:31:30, so it's removed
- 2023-08-10T18:35:30 is in 1 minute interval bewtween 2023-08-10T18:35:00 and 2023-08-10T18:36:00  so it's removed
- Nothing between 2023-08-10T18:37:00 and 2023-08-10T18:37:30 needs to be removed

```
    SELECT time 
      FROM (values
        ('2023-08-10T18:30:30')
      , ('2023-08-10T18:31:30')
      , ('2023-08-10T18:35:00')
      , ('2023-08-10T18:36:00')
      , ('2023-08-10T18:37:00')
      , ('2023-08-10T18:37:30')
      ) s(time)
```

Here's the url https://dbfiddle.uk/u9xXaKHX

Comment: Please, read and update your question accordingly [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you drop the seconds from your timestamps, everything within the same minute will group together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the URL provided I could match the expected output this way (it's not particularly elegant):

```
with sample as (
    SELECT time::timestamp FROM (values
        ('2023-08-10T18:30:30')                -- keep
      , ('2023-08-10T18:31:00') -- to be removed
      , ('2023-08-10T18:31:30')                -- keep
      , ('2023-08-10T18:35:00')                -- keep
      , ('2023-08-10T18:35:30') -- to be removed
      , ('2023-08-10T18:36:00')                -- keep
      , ('2023-08-10T18:37:00')                -- keep
      , ('2023-08-10T18:37:30')                -- keep
      ) s(time)
   )
select min(time) as time
from sample
union 
select
    coalesce(ljl.nxt_time, t.time) as time
from sample as t
left join lateral (
    select n.time as nxt_time
    from sample as n
    where n.time >= t.time + interval '1 minute'
    order by n.time
    limit 1
    ) ljl on true
order by time
```

| time |
| --- |
| 2023-08-10 18:30:30 |
| 2023-08-10 18:31:30 |
| 2023-08-10 18:35:00 |
| 2023-08-10 18:36:00 |
| 2023-08-10 18:37:00 |
| 2023-08-10 18:37:30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PmFBT13E)

---

**original reply**

A generic approach to this is to simply generate a series, but in this case you are just generating many rows due to the small time unit. Once the time series exists left join your data to that series to form 1 minute ranges, so that no matter how accurate your timestamp data is they will still form non-overlapping 1 minute duration intervals.

```
SELECT
      series.minute
    , count(my_table.my_timestamp) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT generate_series(TIMESTAMP '2023-08-26'
                         , TIMESTAMP '2023-08-27'
                         , interval '1 minute') AS minute
    ) AS series
LEFT JOIN my_table ON my_table.my_timestamp >= series.minute
                  AND my_table.my_timestamp <  series.minute + interval '1 minute'
GROUP BY series.minute
ORDER BY series.minute
```

Note it would also be possible to use the following approach to the joining of your data to the ranges:

```
LEFT JOIN my_table ON date_trunc('minute', my_table.my_timestamp) = series.minute
```

but such an approach may remove the query's ability to use an index on the "my_timestamp" column.

**nb** if you only want rows where there are matched rows then use an `inner join` instead of the left join shown above

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer. In this question, the intervals are generated based on input time stamp.
"2023-08-10T18:30:30", "2023-08-10T18:31:00","2023-08-10T18:31:30" -> "18:30:30-18:31:30"
"2023-08-10T18:35:00","2023-08-10T18:35:30"-> "18:35:00-18:35:30"
If we use generate_series, we'll only have intervals starting at either middle of a minute or start of a minute. we can't satify both.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to convey with those 6 timestamps (very unclear!). Have a look at this: https://dbfiddle.uk/nNQbKGdy if possible put in the timestamp pairs you want to see used, then press [Run] & then copy/paste that URL - maybe then I can understand the problem

Comment: Here's the url https://dbfiddle.uk/u9xXaKHX with more detailed explaination.

Comment: I think I now understand what you were asking for. I have added a new query (at the top!) - I also edited the question which is where the further details really should be. Please in future SQL relate question provide **sample data** and **expected result** - having both of these really helps communicate what you are seeking.